# Get text at the bookmark

Tags: c#, ms-word, com

I'm using Microsoft.Interop.Word for my app to get data from the form. There are bookmarks in the text. That is how i get them:

```
var orderedBoomarks = WordDocument.Bookmarks.Cast<Bookmark>().OrderBy(d => d.Start).ToList();                        

foreach (Bookmark bookmark in orderedBoomarks)
     dataTable.Rows.Add(bookmark.Name.ToString());
```

Are there any ways to get exact the **text** at the bookmark not its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can address the bookmark's `Range.Text` property:

```
string bookmarkContent = bookmark.Range.Text;
```

Note that this assumes the bookmark *contains* something. If you're viewing the bookmark non-printing characters a bookmark can look [like this] (square brackets surround content) or Ilike this (an Ibeam marks a position between characters). Only the square bracket type of bookmark will return *meaningful* `Range.Text`; the Ibeam type will return a zero-length string.

Comment: Here comes a maybe dumb question, can i manually (in the document) insert some text to bookmark?

Comment: @Dmitry If I correctly understand what you're asking, yes. But you should post that as a new question and, if my answer is what you need for this question, please mark it / upvote it, whatever...